# How to properly catch errors - react-query next.js 13 route handlers

Tags: next.js, axios, react-query, mutation, tanstackreact-query

I am working on a small application in which I want to check before the user signs up, if that email has already been registered and if so, respond with an error.

For that to happen I am sending the following response in my route.ts file to the frontend.

```
return new Response("User already exists", {status: 409})  
or
return new Response("User added", {status: 200})
```

adding a user works fine and there is no problem but when I am trying to add a user a twice, it spams my console with an axion about the 409 error message even though I am catching that error and displaying a toast notification. How can I avoid that from happening and why is this happening?

````
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof UserValidator>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(UserValidator),
    defaultValues: {
      website: "",
      email: "",
    },

  })


  const {mutate: createUser, error, isLoading} = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => {return axios.post('/api/user', form.getValues()).then(res => res.data)},
    onError: (err) => {
      if(err instanceof AxiosError){
        if(err.response?.status === 409){
          return toast({
            title: "This username already exists",
            description: "Choose a different name",
            variant: "destructive"
          })
        }
      }
    },
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("Success")
    }
  })

  const onSubmit = () => {
    createUser()
  }

  return(
    <>
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={`space-y-8 ${showForm ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <div className="flex">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Email" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="website"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Website</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Website" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        </div>
        <Button type="submit" isLoading={isLoading}>Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
    </>

  )```
````

Answer (score 0):

React Query logs failed responses to the console in dev mode. In v4 (current latest version), you can pass a custom logger to the QueryClient to avoid that.

Starting with v5, custom loggers will be removed and failed responses will no longer be logged at all to the console - only real warnings that need to be addressed by developers, like wrong QueryKeys, will be logged.

Note that nothing should be logged in production in either version - these are development only logs.